# Ordenar variable según su frecuencia

Tags: r

Necesito ordenar una variable tipo factor de mi data frame según las veces que aparece. Estoy probando funciones como *sort()* o *order()* pero no acabo de encontrar la forma de hacerlo.

Qué función habría que utilizar?

Gracias!

Ampliando un poco la información. El dataframe en cuestión tiene éste aspecto:

[image: head(employee)]

Esa variable puede tomar 9 valores distintos:

[image: table(employee$JobRole]

Lo que necesito es ordenar esos valores de más a menos frecuencia, es decir, primero debería aparecer "Sales Executive", después "Research Scientist", etc.

Comment: Deberías ser más específico con tu pregunta y ponernos un ejemplo de los datos que tienes sobre la mesa y los resultados que esperas obtener. Por favor, detalla más la pregunta.

Comment: He añadido algo más de información, a ver si así queda más claro lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con:

```
sort(table(employee$JobRole),decreasing=T)
```

Saludos